# Is there a way to make the autopopup for intellij autocomplete only show up when 3 characters have been typed?

Tags: intellij-idea, autocomplete

Autocomplete is nice and having it pop up automatically is nice, but it tries to pop up way too early. I'd manually invoke autocomplete if I wanted to run it on a single character name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such built-in way. But it's possible by writing a custom plugin, by overriding com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionConfidence#shouldSkipAutopopup method in an extension.